# Public method not firing in SignalR

Tags: signalr

I have a simple application, like a chat, integrated with `SignalR`. I added a new method on my Hub and a new function on client side, like you can see below.

The problem is, my method called `SendMessageChat` isn't firing, because occurs the following error

`TypeError: chat2.server.SendMessageChat is not a function`

but the method `chat2.server.send` works fine, and I don't know why my second method doesn't work. Can someone help me ?

**JavaScript**

```
$(function () {

    var chat2 = $.connection.redirectTask;

    chat2.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message) {
         // Do something here
    };

    chat2.client.sendMessage = function (name, message) {
         // Do something here
    };

    //$.connection.hub.logging = true;
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {

        /* BUTTON CLICK IN ANOTHER PAGE */ 
        $('#btnFinish').click(function () {
                chat2.server.send($.cookie("User"), $("#lista :selected").text());
        });

        /* CASE HIT ENTER INSIDE THE TEXT FIELD IN CHAT */
        $(document).on("keypress", "#txtChat", function (e) {
            var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
            if (code == 13) {                
                var message = $(this).val();                
                $(this).val("");
                chat2.server.SendMessageChat($.cookie("User"), message);
            }
        });
    });    
});
```

**SERVER SIDE**

```
public class RedirectTask : Hub
{
    public void Send(string nome, string message)
    {
        Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);            
    }

    public void SendMessageChat(string nome, string message)
    {
        Clients.All.sendMessage(name, message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried changing to chat2.server.sendMessageChat(...? I know signalR uses camel casing I just can't recall if that's also for Server side method names as well...

Comment: @Pepto good to know, it works now. I've try all in lower case, but with your help it works now.

Comment: Cool. I looked it up to be certain, posted it as an answer before seeing your comment below =) happy coding!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Reference](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-server#methodnames)

Need to change to

```
chat2.server.sendMessageChat($.cookie("User"), message);
```

**Camel-casing of method names in JavaScript clients**

By default, JavaScript clients refer to Hub methods by using a camel-cased version of the method name.  SignalR automatically makes this change so that JavaScript code can conform to JavaScript conventions.

*Server*

```
public void NewContosoChatMessage(string userName, string message)
```

*JavaScript client using generated proxy*

```
contosoChatHubProxy.server.newContosoChatMessage(userName, message);
```

If you want to specify a different name for clients to use, add the HubMethodName attribute.

*Server*

```
[HubMethodName("PascalCaseNewContosoChatMessage")]
public void NewContosoChatMessage(string userName, string message)
```

*JavaScript client using generated proxy*

```
contosoChatHubProxy.server.PascalCaseNewContosoChatMessage(userName, message);
```